# Calculate number of NaN's based on two separate unique columns

Tags: python

I am new to python and I have tried to read multiple books and websites to figure this out but I am at a loss.  I have a csv file I am reading in python that contains precipitation data for 84 climate stations throughout the U.S.  I need to calculate the number of NaN's per year per station. This is short example of what my file looks like:

```
station_id year month element 1 2 3 4  5 6 7   8 9   10 etc.
210018     1916 1     PRCP    0 0 1 10 5 4 0   3 NaN NaN 
210018     1916 2     PRCP    1 4 5 11 3 4 NaN 4 2   1
210019     1917 1     PRCP    1 0 4 55 0 0 0   1 1   3
210019     1917 2     PRCP    8 9 9 12 9 9 9   1 3   4
```

station_id etc are the column names and for each station_id I have 100 years (1910-2010) and 12 months.  element is always PRCP and 1 2 3 4 5 etc. represent days in a month and extend to 31.  So in the example above I would need to find out that there are 3 NaN's in the year 1916 for station 210018 and zero NaN's for station 210019.  If anyone can help or even point me to a website where I can further research this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count how many NaNs are in a row with list.count() and sum the counts in a dictionary keyed by year (or station or anything else).

```
from csv import reader
nan_counts = {}
with open('/path/to/file') as file:
    file_reader = reader(file)
    next(file_reader)  # Skip the first row of headers
    for row in file_reader:
        year, data = row[1], row[4:]
        nan_counts[year] = data.count('NaN') + nan_counts.get(year, 0)
```

Comment: I tried inputting the above code but I think I still have something wrong.  This is how I interpreted it but python doesn't recognize the code as being finished yet.  I used:                                                                      >with open('C:/Users/spotter/Documents/ESSP 502/Final >Project/Manipulated Data/converteddata.csv') as file:
>    file_reader=reader(df)  next(file_reader) #Skip the first row of headers
   for row in file_reader:
       1916, data=row[1], row[4:]
      nan_counts[1916]=data.count('NaN' + nan_counts.get(1916, 0)

Comment: The `year` variable should just be left as `year`, not substituted with the actual year number. After that code you'll have a `nan_count` dictionary that looks like this `{'1916': 3, '1917': 0}` and you can access the counts like this `number_of_nans_in_1916 = nan_counts['1916']`

Comment: Also, in case your csv is tab-separated instead of comma-separated you can use `file_reader = reader(file, delimiter='\t')`

Comment: Also don't forget to close the parentheses after `'NaN'` so it looks like `data.count('NaN')`

Comment: The code did run, but it returned all zeroes for NaN per year (and station_id for that matter).  I tried both 'NaN' and NAN. Thank you for getting me to this point, though It is really useful to switch the code between station_id and year.

Comment: It was because it was not recognizing the NaN's properly.  I changed all of them to WORK and it executed.

Comment: Great! :) If you're satisfied with my service, leave an upvote :P

Comment: I can't upvote quite yet, but I did just realize I can accept your service, thanks again!